# jQuery filter for ul element class within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I have my html like this. I am trying to get the class for each `<ul>` element inside the div with `id = 'accordion'`. Is there a simple way to query this using jQuery? I have been looking at the documentation but didn't find something that I could use straight up. For instance, I want to do something along the lines of:

`$("#accordion").filter()`

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section1">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section2">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section3">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var arrayOfClassNames = $("#accordion *").map(function() {
if($(this).attr('class'))
    return this.className;
}).get();
console.log(arrayOfClassNames);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section1">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section2">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section3">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target any element inside the *div* with `$('#accordion *')`. Then check whether the current element has the *class* attribute or not.

Try the following way:

```js
$('#accordion *').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('class'))
    console.log($(this).attr('class') + ' is in ' + $(this)[0].nodeName);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section1">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section2">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section3">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to get all the classes as an array use `filter()` and `map()` like the following way:

```js
let allClass = $('#accordion *').filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr('class')
}).get().map(el => el.className);

console.log(allClass);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section1">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section2">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section3">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` function like

```
$("#accordion").find("")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#accordion').find('ul')` to get all the `<ul>` elements. Then you can access the class of those elements.

```js
$('#accordion').find('ul').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section1">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section2">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section3">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the code below to get the class of each ul element :

```
$('#accordion ul').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use just `find()` with `each()` method of jquery like below:-

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#accordion div ul').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
    })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section1">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section2">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="section3">
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com"> List item three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```